# Equivalent definition of $C^k(\overline \Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have found some posts about equivalent definitions of $C^k(\overline \Omega)$:

[Equivalent definitions of $C^r(\Omega)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44562/equivalent-definitions-of-cr-omega)

[Definition of convergence in $C^\infty(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399861/definition-of-convergence-in-c-infty-omega)

[Relationship among the function spaces $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ and $C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561560/relationship-among-the-function-spaces-c-c-infty-omega-c-c-infty-overli)

However, they all haven't answered the following question:

> Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded subset in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Denote
>   $$C^k(\overline{\Omega}):= \{ u \in C^k(\Omega): D^\alpha f \text{ is uniformly continuous on } \Omega, \text{ for all }|\alpha|\leq k \}$$
>   and
>   $$D^k(\overline {\Omega}):= \{ u: \text{ there exists }\Omega' \supset \overline{\Omega} \text{ and }g \in C^k(\Omega') \text{ such that }u = g|_{\Omega}\}.$$
>   Under which conditions (of $\Omega$), one has $C^k(\overline{\Omega)} = D^k(\overline{\Omega})$?

Thanks for your helps.